# Sort different li elements with same class level

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have an unordered list as follows

```
<ul>
    <li class="A">abb</li>
        <li class="B">dbb</li>
            <li class="C">zbb</li>
            <li class="C">abb</li>
        <li class="B">ybb</li>
            <li class="C">abb</li>
            <li class="C">zbb</li>
            <li class="C">zab</li>

    <li class="A">zbb</li>

    <li class="A">xbb</li>

    <li class="A">cbb</li>
        <li class="B">bbb</li>
            <li class="C">cbb</li>
            <li class="C">abb</li>
</ul>
```

This is a `grand parent` > `parent` > `child` relationship and I wish to alphabetically order them whilst maintaining the individual relationship structure. The markup can not be changed on import unfortunately as it is generated elsewhere.

Desired output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="A">abb</li>
        <li class="B">dbb</li>
            <li class="C">abb</li>
            <li class="C">zbb</li>
        <li class="B">ybb</li>
            <li class="C">abb</li>
            <li class="C">zab</li>
            <li class="C">zbb</li>

    <li class="A">cbb</li>
        <li class="B">bbb</li>
            <li class="C">abb</li>
            <li class="C">cbb</li>

    <li class="A">xbb</li>

    <li class="A">zbb</li>
</ul>
```

I have never encountered this issue before. Whenever I have had to order a list it has been a case of ordering the list in it's entirety. Has anybody got any clever suggestions or advice on how I could approach this problem.

Current Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p70Lagyp/

Comment: It's valid markup. I have stated the markup can not be changed.

Comment: Sort what, disregarding the fact that there's no nesting, just indentation, they don't really have any classes to sort by, all the grandparents have class `A`, all the parents have class `B` etc. the desired output doesn't really make sense based on classes

Comment: @adeneo sorry, I'm not quite sure what you don't understand. Top level `A` has been alphabetically sorted based on text content. The same goes for their respective children.

Comment: It looks like you got it resolved using sort. That is what I was about to recommend.

Comment: @JackShultz unfortunately `sort` completely ignores the relationship structure. I know that nesting via multiple `ul` would be the ideal. But i don't have control over the markup.

Comment: So you want to sort based on the ***content*** limited somehow to classes

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you want the lists grouped by class following order ABC? Then within each group sort by content. Correct?

Comment: @JackShultz yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, and iterates multiple times, but this should work

```
$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.' + this.className).appendTo(this);
}).each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.' + this.className).addBack().sort(function(a,b) {
        var _a = $(a).clone(),
            _b = $(b).clone();

        _a.add(_b).children().remove();

        return _a.text().localeCompare( _b.text() );
    }).appendTo($(this).parent())
}).each(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (parent.prop('tagName').toLowerCase() === 'li')
        $(this).siblings('.' + this.className).addBack().insertAfter(parent);
});
```

**Explanation :** First it iterates over all the LI's, getting the next elements that doesn't have the same class as the current which creates a nested hierarchy to be able to sort them individually.
When the nested structure is created, it iterates again, this time getting all siblings with the same class, and adding the original back with `addBack`, and then sorting them all based on text content, which means they have to be clones and have child LI's removed.
Lastly it puts the LI's back in the parent, undoing the nested structure.

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution. I've never used `addBack()` before. I may read up on this to improve my understanding on exactly what is going on. Thank you very much.